# Syntax Error JSONLoader

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am trying to import my models from c4d into three.js.
I know there is a OBJLoader which works fine for me. If I want to use my exported wavefront (.obj) and convert it with **convert_obj_three.py** it doesn't return any errors and the json-file looks fine.

But if I want to load the generated .js-file in my three.js-script, it returns:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;**

This is what I've tried:

```
var loader2 = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader2.load('assets/models/test.js', createScene);
function createScene(){
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh();
    scene.add(mesh);
}
```

test.js: http://www.file-upload.net/download-7296129/test.js.html

error: http://www.file-upload.net/download-7296139/screenie.png.html

here is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - OBJ loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: gray;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - OBJLoader test
        </div>

        <script src="assets/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/OBJLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="assets/TrackballControls.js"></script>

        <script src="assets/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, controls, renderer;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


            init();
            animate();


            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 900;

                // controls

                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

                controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
                controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
                controls.panSpeed = 2;

                controls.noZoom = false;
                controls.noPan = false;

                controls.staticMoving = true;
                controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xfff3dd );
                scene.add( ambient );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                // model

                var loader2 = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                loader2.load('assets/models/test.js', function (geometry, materials){

                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
                    scene.add(mesh);

                });

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                controls.handleResize();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                controls.update();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the contents of `assets/models/test.js`

Comment: I don't think you're giving us enough information to solve your problem here.  Can you check your console and tell us what line the syntax error is occuring on?  Nothing stands out here.

Comment: share the content of "test.js", there could be some syntax errors related to ";".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function to load json file:

```
THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.load = function ( url, callback, texturePath )



loader2.load('assets/models/test.js', function(geometry, materials){

   mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
   scene.add(mesh);

});
```

Comment: I didn't chose this because of this page here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1476

Comment: Discussion is one year old. Code has changed.

Comment: Ok i've changed my code to your version. Still gives the same error.

Comment: Unexpected token error is not related with JSONLoader, but it's difficult to say when I don't see code. I tried your json and it's working.

Comment: Change `mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));`

Comment: still gives me **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;**

Comment: I just run your code and couldn't find any syntaxError. Check your libraries, maybe some copying mistake.